# Resizing the background image on button

Tags: java, android

I want a background image on a button as I click on the button.for that I have used following aproach.

```java
Button button=findViewById(R.id.button_00);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jerry);
```

background image do appear as I click on the button.but the image is too bigger than the button.Tell me how can i fix this problem.

Comment: Do you want to change background image when we click or focus on button?

Comment: You'll have to resize your image to a smaller dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good, you change the Buttons to ImageButtons and use `android:src` instead of `android:background` For example :

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/button_00"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/jerry"
android:onClick="btn_click" />
```

You can set your image runtime as well

```
ImageButton button=findViewById(R.id.button_00);
button.setImageResource(R.drawable.jerry);
```